# Dynamically updating calculated expression property in Powershells Format-Table

Tags: powershell

I have an array of properties that are generated from a variable SQL query, which I would like to cycle through and assign to properties of the Format-Table commandlet. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't seem to evaluate variables in the "expression" property and I end up with a literal output, such as "$prop.$_" instead of "$prop.ID".

Is there anyway to get the scriptblock in the expression property to evaluate the content of $_?

Here is the specific code I'm running and the output.

Thanks

```
$htable = [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]]@()
$htable = $ncsvDataSet | %{
       @{
         n=$_
         e={$testDataSet.$_}
         align='center'
        }
     }
$htable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              CustomerID
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              LocationID
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              CustomerName
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              ActiveCustomer
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              ServiceContract
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n                              ManagementNetwork
e                              $testDataSet.$_
align                          center
n
```

Comment: You mention `calculated expression` and `Format-Table` yet `Format-Table` is nowhere to be seen on your code.

Comment: Read and follow [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties)

Comment: Santiago, true I'm just having issues dynamically creating the properties, not in using the properties, so my example shows how I'm going about creating the properties hashtables. I can't seem edit the title to clarify.

Comment: JosefZ, thanks, I've gone through the docs on calculated properties. Unfortunately, they don't specifically address the problem I'm having.

Comment: With the information we currently have is quite hard to help you, there is no expected output on your question and even tho we have an idea of what `$ncsvDataSet` contains we have no idea what `$testDataSet` is.

Comment: Sorry, new to asking questions on here. I normally just dig around the interwebs until I find an answer. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to edit my question to update and clarify it. That said, ```$testDataSet``` is a data table pulled from a SQL query. I'm basically, trying to format the table for output to pdf. The problem is that the SQL queries vary, so I want to be able to dynamically change the calculated properties to reflect the queries as they change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, which was to use

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock()
```

to create a scriptblock for the expression property of `Format-Table`. Doing so, I could pass values dynamically into the property.